# HTT 3.3.1.3.Reduce the class of inner anodyne morphisms to generators

Tags: higher-category-theory

This is the first part of Lurie's HTT 3.3.1.3:

> Proposition 3.3.1.3. Let $p: X \rightarrow S$ be a Cartesian fibration and let $T \rightarrow$ $S$ be a categorical equivalence. Then the induced map $X \times_{S} T \rightarrow X$ is a categorical equivalence.

> Proof. We first suppose that the map $T \rightarrow S$ is inner anodyne. By means of a simple argument, we may reduce to the case where $T \rightarrow S$ is a middle horn inclusion $\Lambda_{i}^{n} \subseteq \Delta^{n}$, where $0<i<n$.

I can't figure out what this "simple argument" is, which allows us reduce to the case $\Lambda_{i}^{n} \subseteq \Delta^{n}$.

I know $\Lambda_{i}^{n} \subseteq \Delta^{n}$ generates the class of anodyne morphisms via transfinite composition,retract and pushout. Denote the property mentioned in this proposition by $R(T\rightarrow S)$. So we have to check:

1. For $f_i:T_i\rightarrow T_{i+1}$ anodyne,$\forall i (R(f_i))$ implies $R(f)$,where $f$ is their composition.
2. For $F$,a pushout of $f$ where $R(f)$ holds and $f$ is anodyne, we have $R(F)$.
3. For $F$,a retract of $f$ where $R(f)$ holds and $f$ is anodyne, we have $R(F)$.

I'm ok with 1, but soon get confused about 2 and 3 since they concern not only about pull-back but also push-out.

Thanks for any helpful comments.

Comment: You will find that in the category of simplicial sets pullbacks have excellent colimit preservation properties.

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks, I know how this is done now.